# How can i make a reset password function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever i run this code, i recieve a blank screen on submission. The code does not seem to work and i'm unsure why. Can anyone see an issue? I've checked it for syntax already mutliple times.

Controller:

```
public function changepwd(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldpassword','Old Password','required|trim|xss_clean|callback_change');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1','New Password','required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Confirm Password','required|trim|matches[password1]');

if($this->form_validation->run()= true){
    redirect('admin');
   }else{
$this->form_validation->set_message('change','info is wrong');
redirect('admin');  
}
}

public function change(){
$this->load->view('error_display');
$oldpass = $this->input->post('oldpassword');
if(isset($oldpass)){
    if($this->input->post('password1') == $this->input->post('password2')){

        $session=$this->session->userdata("logged_in");
        $username= $session['username'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM database where username='$username'";
            $result = $this->db->query($query);
            $row=$result->row();
            $pass = $row->password;
            $s= $row->salt;
            $user_old_pass = sha1($s.$oldpass);

            if($pass == $user_old_pass){
                $new = substr(uniqid(rand(), true), 0, 20);
                $users_password = $this->input->post('pass1');
                $new_password = sha1($new.$user_password);
                $data = array($new,$new_password);  
                $this->update_model->insert_model($data);
                $this->form_validation->set_message('change','saved');
                $this->load->view('admin');

            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('change','<p class="error">Incorrect Password</p>');
                return false;
                redirect('admin');  
            }
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('change','passwords dont match');
        return false;   
        redirect('admin');
    };

}else{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('change','old password is not entered');
    return false;
    redirect('admin');
}
```

model:

```
 function login($data)
    {
    $this->db->update('database', $data);
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your

```
if($this->form_validation->run()= true){
```

should be

```
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
```

because you are redirecting every time to  `'admin'`

Comment: Ah, no more blank page, just errors i need to fix. Thanks! Can you see anything that may be wrong with the code?

Comment: This is the one currently  "Call to a member function insert_model() on a non-object"

Comment: Ah have you loaded the model 'update_model' in your code it should be like $this->load->model("update_model");

Comment: @Bakitai I have updated my answer because if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { is the correct condition

Comment: thanks, i tried loading the model before my line as above and it didn't change. Now i'm just loading the model itself and getting this error "Class 'Insert_model' not found in //filepath". Any idea? I need to pass the array of the salt and password into the model.

Comment: Hi 'Insert_model' should be function , so in your update_model class you should have a function called 'Insert_model'

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Working now!